# Do I need a Redis ConnectionMultiplexer for each pub/sub subscription?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, publish-subscribe, stackexchange.redis

I have a .Net Core Web Api setup where I expose an endpoint that is basically a forever-frame. I am constrained by an API contract that forces me to expose it as such.

That forever-frame pushes data that is received from a Redis pub/sub channel. I will have multiple listeners on this endpoint, and they should basically be individual subscribers to the same channel.

I use StackExchange.Redis.

There is one thing I cannot wrap my head around, and that is how to use the ConnectionMultiplexer in this scenario. Everywhere I read about it I am told to have one global ConnectionMultiplexer. But if I do that won't I unsubscribe all subcribers when one leaves and shuts down a subscription to the channel that they are all listening to?

If I don't then I will run into a memory leak I am sure.

A global ConnectionMultiplexer keeps the number of connections to Redis at a minimum, but I don't see any way to avoid it here.

Is there something I have misunderstood?

Answer (score 0):

Always use the same instance of ConnectionMultiplexer, or you will lose the benefits of using a multiplexer.

I had a similar issue when calling unsubscribe on a channel caused all subscribers to unsubscribe too.

If you look at the ISubscriber interface, there is two ways to subscribe to a channel :

```
void Subscribe(RedisChannel channel, Action<RedisChannel, RedisValue> handler, CommandFlags flags = CommandFlags.None);
ChannelMessageQueue Subscribe(RedisChannel channel, CommandFlags flags = CommandFlags.None);
```

I took the second one and it solved my problem.

Comment: Can you elaborate on it more that how can you not unsubscribe all other subscriptions by calling just one unsubscribe somewhere in context where we are using ConnectionMultiplexer?